# Resizing A Macbook Pro Partition

Tags: macos, partition, error, dual-boot

I am trying to dual boot with linux on my 2012 MacBook Pro running MacOs High Sierra. Whenever I try to add a partition for my linux system, It says this: "**A problem occurred; undoing Logical Volume resize changes.Unable to perform your specific resize request while busy encrypting.Operation failed…**"

Does anybody know what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to perform your specific resize request while busy encrypting

this part indicates me your drive is currently mounted and some write operations are being encrypted to disk.

while encryption of data (write operations) is happening, you cannot resize.

I believe you have three options

1. If you have an extra drive with a TimeMachine backup, you can delete the volume, make a new partition and restore backup
   See this other answer for a hint.
   https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/349215/415753
2. Umount your drive and do offline resize, you probably need to reboot into diagnostic mode.
3. Disable disk encryption before doing the resize, which is likely going to need to be happening offline anyway.

Note that Offline means not-mounted also known as "while not using it".
If that's your root filesystem, then you need to boot into diagnostic mode, or with a rescue Live disk.

I believe 1) is the safest.
You should do a backup before whichever options you choose

Answer (score 0):

Have you activate Filevault recently on your Mac?
If yes, you may wait that this encryption end.

`fdsetup status` on terminal can give information.
Keep in mind that the encryption requires electrical connection of the Mac.